# How do I assign a global variable to the results of javascript map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a mock data object, I created a 2 global JS arrays and assigning them to inside map, and printing, but the object doesn't prints comes as undefined.

Following is what I tried

```js
var mock = {
  "collection_data_status_list": [{
    "input_status_list": [{
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry0"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry1"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry2"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry3"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry4"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }],
    "output_status_list": [{
      "destination_id": "d0",
      "destination_context_id": "t1",
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry0"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }]
  }, {}],
  "query_options": {
    "page_token": "1",
    "page_size": 100
  },
  "result": {
    "request_result": "ACCEPTED",
    "error": {}
  }
};

var input_list = [];
var output_list = [];
var newObj = {};
var new1 = mock.collection_data_status_list;
debugger;
var finalOutput = new1.map(function(item) {
  var input_list = [];
  var output_list = [];

  var newObj = {};
  newObj = {
    input_list: item.input_status_list,
    output_list: item.output_status_list
  };
  return newObj;
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: `var newObj = {};` inside your `.map` callback will create a *new* variable that is different to the `newObj` in the outer scope. Since the inner variable shadows the outer one, any references to `newObj` inside the callback refer to the inner variable. So, `console.log(newObj);` prints an object that was never modified

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Don't you want `console.log(finalOutput)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: What's the purpose of `var input_list` and `var output_list`? You never use those variables.

Comment: there is something wrong with the json. but as Barmar stated, you are probably looking for console.log(finalOutput)

Comment: Yes finalOutput works.. But still was expecting variables input_list & output_list to print values directly..

Comment: Something like this - var new1 = mock.collection_data_status_list;
var input_list = [];
var output_list = [];
debugger;
var finalOutput = new1.map(function(item){
//var newObj = {};
 //newObj = {
      input_list=item.input_status_list;
       output_list= item.output_status_list;
    //  };
     // return newObj; 
});

console.log(finalOutput);

Answer (score 0):

```
var mock = {
  "collection_data_status_list": [{
    "input_status_list": [{
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry0"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry1"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry2"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry3"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }, {
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry4"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }],
    "output_status_list": [{
      "destination_id": "d0",
      "destination_context_id": "t1",
      "device_id": "r0",
      "sensor_data": {
        "snmp_yang_sensor": {
          "path": "IF-MIB:IF-MIB\/ifTable\/ifEntry0"
        }
      },
      "collection_status": {
        "state": "ACTIVE_STATE",
        "error": {},
        "reported_time": "1569948062"
      }
    }]
  }, {}],
  "query_options": {
    "page_token": "1",
    "page_size": 100
  },
  "result": {
    "request_result": "ACCEPTED",
    "error": {}
  }
};

var new1 = mock.collection_data_status_list;
        var input_list = [];
        var output_list = [];
        debugger;
        var finalOutput = new1.map(function(item){
               input_list=item.input_status_list;
               output_list= item.output_status_list; 
        });

        console.log(finalOutput);
```

Comment: The above one displays finalOutput as undefined